# Why is my Auth0 token always coming back as invalid when sent from iOS to node.js server?

Tags: ios, node.js, express, jwt, auth0

I'm using Auth0's service for an iOS app with a server built on node.js and express.js. I've followed Auth0's docs and seed projects as best I can, but the server keeps complaining that the tokens I'm sending from my iOS application are invalid. Here's some of my code:

From the server - the authentication and route declarations, as specified in the [Auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/nodejs)

```
var authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});


app.use('/api', authenticate);
app.use('/api/userquery', queries);
```

And from iOS, setting the header for a request (using AFNetworking):

```
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

I know for a fact the request is being sent properly because it works fine for paths that don't require authentication. Lastly, here's the error I receive on the server side:

```
GET /api/userquery/currentUser 401 7.185 ms - 436
UnauthorizedError: invalid token
    at /node_modules/express-jwt/lib/index.js:100:22
    at /node_modules/jsonwebtoken/index.js:155:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Have you checked the response from the server? It could be an object that contains URL and body with token.

Comment: On the iOS side, I just get this error in response: Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"

Comment: What token are you sending? Make sure it's the `id_token` and not the `access_token` (the latter is not a JWT).

Comment: It is indeed the idToken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was just that I failed to unwrap the token after pulling it out of keychain. Instead of sending "Bearer [token]" in the Authorization header, I was sending "Bearer [Optional(token)]".